# How to show image of youtube video after adding url link in objective c

Tags: uialertview

I have an application that is working with one UI Image view. On clicking on the image view i get a UI alert view asking for a video link . Once you have mentioned the link the UI Image view should contain the video image of the particular selected video.

What i have is a working till accepting the URL link , but the video image is not getting rendered in the UI Image view.

Comment: Can you show us your code? We don't have much to go on here.